# Optimization equality for composition of nondecreasing functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization, function-and-relation-composition

So I came across an equality related to optimization in a paper and I'm having difficulty understanding why this is true.

Let $f_{1}(\mathbf{x}),\ldots,f_{m}(\mathbf{x})$ be $m$ functions, with $f_{i}(\mathbf{x}):\mathbb{R}^{n}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{dom}\;f_{i}(\mathbf{x})=\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Furthermore, let $f_{i}(\mathbf{x})=\underset{y_{i}\in\mathbb{R}}{\mathrm{max}\;}\hat{f}_{i}(\mathbf{x},y_{i})$. Let $g(z):\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a nondecreasing function, with $\mathrm{dom}\;g=\mathbb{R}$. Let $h(\mathbf{w}):\mathbb{R}^{m}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{dom}\;h=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $h$ nondecreasing in each component. Then the following equality holds:

$$\underset{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}}{\mathrm{max}\;}h([g(f_{1}(\mathbf{x})),\ldots,g(f_{m}(\mathbf{x}))]^{T})=\underset{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X},y_{i}\in\mathbb{R}}{\mathrm{max}\;}h([g(\hat{f}_{1}(\mathbf{x},y_{1})),\ldots,g_{m}(\hat{f}_{m}(\mathbf{x},y_{m}))]^{T})$$

My intuition is that we can somehow move the $\mathrm{max}$ operator outside since $g$ is nondecreasing and $h$ is nondecreasing in each component. I'd really appreciate if somebody could formally explain this (or let me know if my thinking is wrong!).

Thanks and cheers :)

**Edit:** Fixed a typo. Thanks @LinAlg!

**Edit 2:** I should emphasize that $\mathit{g}$ and $h$ are *nondecreasing*. This means that there could potentially be regions where the functions stay constant. I'd appreciate if someone could explain whether this would alter the equality in any way compared to the setting in which both $\mathit{g}$ and $h$ are *strictly increasing*.

Comment: Take $h(x,y) = x+y$, $g$ the identity function, then the claim is $\max_x \{ \max_y f_1(x,y) + \max_y f_2(x,y) \} = \max{x,y} \{ f_1(x,y) + f_2(x,y) \}$. Are you sure all $y_i$ on the right hand side are the same?

Comment: @LinAlg, you are correct that this is true for $h(x,y)=x+y$, and $g$ as the identity function. I’m wondering how to prove this in general without assuming specific functions for $f$ and $g$. And thanks for catching the error— the $y_i$s are indeed not the same on the RHS. I’ll edit that to correct it.

Comment: Now it makes sense and your intuition is right. Try proving it by contradiction.

Comment: @LinAlg After 10 solid minutes of thinking, I confess that I’m not even certain about how to begin to prove this by contradiction. Could you please elaborate on your hint? And just to confirm, are you saying that the equality holds? Thanks!